# Should I learn Unity C# for PC before learning Unity for Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to start learning Unity, I'm a web developer and I have a decent level in C# but I've never touched Unity before.

I mainly want to create games for Android (maybe iOS in the future), there are many courses on the internet but I'm wodering if I need to have a good understanding of Unity PC/Mac.. before trying to learn Unity for Android.

I found this course : https://www.udemy.com/course/unitycourse/, It seems like a it's a complete and detailed one, but it has nothing to do with Android. Should I learn something like this first?

I'll appreciate any advices, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an android developer that made a few games with unity, I think that if your end goal is to develop for android so just start with that..
I developed several apps(games) for android and I didn't had any problem with it and I didn't even know C# before.

Besides, you will get a better idea about how to make an optimized app that can work well on Android.

You can find some great Videos on youtube, for example this [channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/Brackeys)

Answer (score 1):

Do a quick project on the desktop first.

The setup required to build for android devices will be an extra hurdle to get over, so I would recommend starting with a project that you can develop directly on the desktop, if the primary goal is just learning.

Besides the small amount of extra work it takes setting up Unity3d to build for Android, it will also be a slower to build and run the project on a smartphone than just running it directly on a desktop.  And there will always be a lot of trial and error when you are still learning.

And if you think ahead, it might be no problem porting your desktop-project to mobile after a while. Touch can be pretty similar to a mouse, and Unity3d won't care about the difference in many cases.

Comment: I understand, I just don't want to "waste" my time learning Unity for PC if it's a lot different from learning Unity from Android, because I'm not interested in PC. But if my skills in Unity PC can be used for Android too, then it's Ok for me

Comment: If you create a game for PC, it should also work for Android (unless you need drag controls and the like, but that can come later). Besides, you want it to work for PC anyway so you can debug properly and have a faster iteration speed.

Comment: @AndreasHassing Ok, thanks a lot.